# need help querying a database using php

Tags: php, html

Hello guys im learning php and just started today. I was on yahoo web hosting and learning DB also for the first time. I was able to post a firstName and LastName into the mysql datatbase. But now i want to be able to query the name and be able to display the names which i searched. My php file isnt working and as i am not able to find the name in the database. Please i need help with it and thanks
 Below is my code:

```
<htmL>
<body>
 <p><strong>Query database</strong></p>
<form name="form1" method="post" action="backendfile2.php">
<label><br>
  <br>
 First Name
 <input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname">
 </label>
  <p>
<label>Last Name
 <input type="text" name="lastname" id="lastname">
  </label>
  </p>
 <p>&nbsp;</p>
 <input type="submit" value="Submit">  
 </form>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  </body>
  </html>
```

php file:

```
   <?php
   $con=mysqli_connect("mysql","username","password","207_lab");
 // Check connection
   if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
   }
    $firstname = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['firstname']);
    $lastname = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['lastname']);
     $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT FirstName, LastName FROM User WHERE 
      FirstName = $firstname, LastName = $lastname");

       echo "Name searched = ";
       while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
       echo $row['FirstName'] . " " . $row['LastName'];
    echo "<br>";
        }
         ?>
```

Comment: `"SELECT FirstName, LastName FROM User WHERE 
      FirstName = '$firstname' AND LastName = '$lastname'"`

Comment: Please, [do not use `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/1757964)! They are no longer maintained and are [officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). Learn about [prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://us1.php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://us1.php.net/mysqli). [This article](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide.

Comment: Aside from the quotes already mentioned. Where are you setting your `$firstname` and `$lastname` variables? Are they just not shown?

Comment: @Gohn67 fixing it now

Comment: In case you may have seen [**my answer**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26446311/1415724) before your edit, I too made an edit. Do reload it to see additional information. @user2738145

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per your [**originally posted code/question**](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/26446293/1) since you've made an edit.

---

Use quotes around your variables since they are strings.

```
FirstName = '$firstname', LastName = '$lastname'
```

Checking for errors with

`or die(mysqli_error($con))` to `mysqli_query()` which would have triggered it.

You also need to assign it from POST.

```
$firstname = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['firstname']);
$lastname = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['lastname']);
```

plus

```
WHERE 
  FirstName = $firstname, LastName = $lastname"
```

to, using `AND` and not a comma

```
WHERE 
  FirstName = '$firstname' AND LastName = '$lastname'"
```

Commas are when you use `UPDATE table SET column_x = 'var_1', column_y = 'var_2'`

*Subsequently,* you can replace the `AND` by `OR` depending on the query's criteria.

Add [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to the top of your file(s) which would have given you an `Undefined index...` warning for both variables.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

**Sidenote:** Error reporting should only be done in staging, and never production.

and your present method is open to [**SQL injection**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/). Use [**prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), or [**PDO with prepared statements**](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements).

Comment: @Fred-ii- thanks. Also if a name i searched wasn't in the database how do i got about that. And i want to display an error saying name doesn't exist in database

Comment: @user2738145 You're welcome. You would need to use [`mysqli_num_rows()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php) for that, which is one way of doing it. You may have to post another question for it, but am sure you will find many examples on Stack. I will post a quick example in a comment here, give me a minute.

Comment: @user2738145 Here you go `$numrows=mysqli_num_rows($query);

if($numrows > 0){
die("Record exists already.");
}`

Answer (score 1):

Check your SQL syntax also - looks like it should be:

```
WHERE FirstName = '$firstname' AND LastName = '$lastname'
```